# How To Re-Attach Armature in Blender 2.9

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender, game-development

Currently making my first game in Unity and have been using Blender for the meshes and animations. I followed a simple tutorial to animate the default cube; I've made it look like it's jumping, laughing, and breathing to understand the animation workflow.

However, when I went to import it into Unity I find that it is just an outline of the default cube without the modifiers added. I fixed this by going back into Blender and converting the model to a mesh (made a copy beforehand) which applied the modifiers. Now I can see the cube as it shows in Blender. There's just one problem; it doesn't have the animations attached properly.

All I want to do is re-attach the necessary vertices to the armature so the animations are as they should be. Is that possible?

Here is what was attempted before coming here:

1. Built the armature again and imported the saved animations onto that
2. Searched YouTube for a tutorial on the subject (surprisingly not a lot of tutorials on this)
3. Started to re-animate the new mesh cube to get the same effect but realized it was too tedious
4. Manually applying the modifiers with Ctrl-A which has the same effect as converting to Mesh

Either that, or is there a way to import the cube without applying the modifiers and still having it be a solid model?

[This is the tutorial I followed to animate the Default Cube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaFPEDAF7aI)

If photos, or a video (not sure if I have the software for that), are needed to better understand please ask

Comment: What are you exporting as? The model needs to be in fbx format. Here is a better tutorial. Sabastian goes through everything from modifiers and rigging. Ill start you at video two. Skip any material regarding inverse kinematics. Unless you need that for some reason. He will eventually also show you how to use your modifiers in Unity after blender,

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jp_SqjB0468